# Remove Text from a String in an SSIS Package

Tags: sql, ssis, expression

I am currently updating an already existing SSIS package. 
The current Package pulls data from an Excel Spread Sheet that is provided by our IT Department. It lists Machine Names of Computers and counts it for a License Report.

I currently have the Job (derived column) strip off the M (Mobile) or D (Desktop) from the first part of the machine name so that it returns just the user name, which is what I need for the report.

```
MBRUBAKERBR => BRUBAKERBR
```

However, our IT Department just implemented Windows 7 and with it a new Naming convention. 
Now there is a 76A, B, C or D that is added to the end of all of the updated machines. If the machine has not been updated then it stays with the older Naming Convention (seen Above).

There are also machines that have to stay on XP, their names have been update to have X3A, B, C or D at the end of theirs.

```
MBRUBAKERBR76A or DBRUBAKERX3C
```

What I need is to remove the last part of the name so that I just get the user name out of it for reporting.

The issues is I can't use a LEFT, RIGHT, LTRIM or RTRIM expression as some of the computer names will only have the M or D in front (as they have not yet been upgraded).

What can I do to remove these characters without rebuilding this package?

UPDATE: I would really like to update the existing Expression that Removed the M and D. 
Here is the Expression that I am using.

```
SUBSTRING(Name,2,50)
```

this is in a Derived Column in my SSIS Package.

As for Sample Data here is what it looks like coming in.

```
|      Name      |
| MBrubakerBR76A |
| MBROCKSKX3A    |
| DGOLDBERGZA    |
| MWILLIAMSEL    |
| DEASTST76C     |
| DCUSICKEVX3D   |
```

This is what I want it to return.

```
|      Name      |
| BRUBAKERBR     |
| BROCKSK        |
| GOLDBERGZA     |
| WILLIAMSEL     |
| EASTST         |
| CUSICKEV       |
```

Let me know if you need any more information or examples.

Comment: What if `MORGANAB` comes in? Is that Baile Organa's Mobile device or Alice Morgan's Windows 7 desktop?

Comment: It would look like this MMORGANAB when it came in., I then strip off the first letter (M or D) If we have more than 1 MORGANAB then we usually add an additional character to the Naming, MORGANABI or MORGANABE, etc.

Comment: Show sample data and expected results

Answer (score 1):

First determine if the machine has been upgraded, if it is then strip out last 3 and the first letter. If it has not been upgraded then just strip out the first letter. I avoided Trim functions to keep the code clear.

```
SELECT
machineName,

CASE WHEN RIGHT(machineName, 3) Like '%[0-9]%' THEN
  SUBSTRING(machineName, 2, len(machineName) - 4)
ELSE 
  RIGHT(machineName, len(machineName)-1)
END AS UserName

From MachineList
```

[**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd852/3)

**SSIS Expression**
As pattern matching not working in SSIS expression, try this

```
LEFT(RIGHT(machineName, 3),2)="X3"||LEFT(RIGHT(machineName, 3),2)="76"?SUBSTRING(machineName, 2, len(machineName) - 4):RIGHT(machineName, len(machineName)-1)
```

Comment: SQL Fiddle is awesome!!! thank you for connecting me to that sight. I am a little new to this and the site will be an invaluable resource to me. Thank you again.

Comment: I love SQL fiddle. I also came to know about this site from StackOverflow. There are lot of cloud IDEs like pythonfiddle, jsfiddle. 
Also did my answer helped you? Are you looking for something similar?

Comment: What you have is almost exactly what i am looking for but I need to do this in an expression in an SSIS package. The package is already built and is working so I dont want to tear down the package to get this modification to work. I am playing around with the idea of pulling the data into a staging table first, using your script to transform it with an SQL Task then just connecting my existing Package to the Staging Table for the look-up transformation instead of the Excel Spreadsheet like it is currently. WHat are your thoughts?

Comment: Try something like this in your expression `RIGHT(machineName, 3) Like '%[0-9]%'?SUBSTRING(machineName, 2, len(machineName) - 4):RIGHT(machineName, len(machineName)-1)`

Comment: Ok, I tried the following in my Derived Column `RIGHT(Name, 3) Like '%[0-9]%'?SUBSTRING(Name, 2, len(Name) - 4):RIGHT(Name, len(Name)-1)` But it stayed Red. The Column is labeled "Name" and currently has a `SUBSTRING(Name,2,50)` Expression in it to remove the M or D from the front.

Comment: As like operator and pattern matching doesn't work in SSIS expression try this `LEFT(RIGHT(Name, 3),2)="X3"||LEFT(RIGHT(Name, 3),2)="76"?SUBSTRING(Name, 2, len(Name) - 4):RIGHT(Name, len(Name)-1)`

Comment: I needed to make an alteration per the error codes suggestions, It requested double equals in the statement, let me know if this will cause any issues. `LEFT(RIGHT(Name, 3),2)=="X3"||LEFT(RIGHT(Name, 3),2)=="76"?SUBSTRING(Name, 2, len(Name) - 4):RIGHT(Name, len(Name)-1)`

Comment: UPDATE: I ran the script and it removed the 76A-D's but left the X3A-D's and the leading M and D's that I was originally removing. (were getting closer though)

Comment: You probably need to play with string lengths. Use LTRIM, RTRIM to remove any whitespaces in the machine name. I will try something later to come up with exact expression.

Comment: Excellent. I will also try it in my database and see if I can't get it to work as well. Thank you for all of your help.